# proper way to curl Authorization: Basic with a hash

Tags: php, curl

This curl example works.  The hash is a base64 encode of $username . ':' . $password.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic b2ZmZXJib3NzqGdtYxlsLmNvbupHcmVtbdFuJA==" https://somedomain.com/login
```

The following PHP code does not work and returns "status" : "UNAUTHORIZED", "typeName" : "badCredentials", "typeCode" : [ 401, 0 ]

```
$hash = base64_encode($username . ":" . $password);

echo '<p>' . $hash . '</p>'; //hash works correct

$URL='https://somedomain.com/login';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $hash);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: while it might not be the "proper" way, with basic authentication you can usually specify the username/password in the url like `http://username:password@www.whatever.com/path/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encoding the string twice.

There's no need to use `base64_encode` when using `CURLOPT_USERPWD` because this is what this option do.

So this should work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

If you want to use `base64_encode` you should add an header called 'Authorization' and pass the hash string together:

```
$hash = base64_encode($username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Authorization: Basic $hash"
);
```

Refs:

[`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

[`CURLOPT_USERPWD`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html)